# Varnish not showing custom headers

Tags: debian, varnish

In my Varnish 3 configuration (default.vcl) I configured the following to pass along information via the response headers:

```
sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
        set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
    } else {
       set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }
    set resp.http.X-Cache-Expires = resp.http.Expires;
    set resp.http.X-Test = "LOL";

    # remove Varnish/proxy header
    remove resp.http.X-Varnish;
    remove resp.http.Via;
    remove resp.http.Age;
    remove resp.http.X-Purge-URL;
    remove resp.http.X-Purge-Host;
    remove resp.http.X-Powered-By;
}
```

And yet the only thing I can see is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 8492
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Tue, 05 Feb 2013 10:11:02 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

It doesn't show any headers that we have added inside the `vcl_deliver` method.

**EDIT:** This is my vcl_fetch method:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
    unset beresp.http.Server;
    unset beresp.http.Etag;
    remove req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.rlnclientipaddr;
    set beresp.http.X-Wut = "YAY";

    if (req.url ~ "^/w00tw00t") {
        error 750 "Moved Temporarily";
    }

    # allow static files to be cached for 7 days
    # with a grace period of 1 day
    if (req.url ~ "\.(png|gif|jpeg|jpg|ico|swf|css|js)$") {
        set beresp.ttl = 7d;
        set beresp.grace = 1d;
        return(deliver);
    }

    # cache everythig else for 1 hours
    set beresp.ttl = 1h;

    # grace period of 1 day
    set beresp.grace = 1d;

    return(deliver);
}
```

Anyone got an idea how to solve this as NO custom headers are included in the response headers... As you can see above in my `vcl_fetch` method I add several custom response headers but none of they are showing.

Answer (score 0):

`vcl_deliver` is only called for objects found in cache.  You probably meant to use `vcl_fetch`.

If that's not the issue, you don't show the request you're sending or your `vcl_recv`.  Perhaps you're `pipe`ing, for example?  Try sending a raw request via telnet or netcat and show us both what you sent and received.  And since you're using `vcl_deliver`, do the same request twice so we can debug properly, please.

Comment: Added my `vcl_fetch` method

Comment: @Kenny so I take it that your X-Wut header isn't showing up?  It might be worthwhile to simply dump your entire VCL in here.  In this case, we're looking for mistakes, and requiring you to know where those mistakes are only works if you already know what mistakes you made.  For example, you're modifying the `req` in your `vcl_fetch`, which isn't going to accomplish very much in almost all cases.  This tells me that you probably are building a VCL largely from snippets, which means we need to see the whole kit 'n' caboodle in order to diagnose the cause of the symptoms you're seeing.

Comment: Also, while we're on documentation: please include a complete request/response pair (not just the response as you have above), and the output of "varnishlog" (you can sanitize IP addresses if you'd like, but leave the rest alone, please) during that test.

Comment: It was my browser that was hiding these headers ;)

Comment: @Kenny: Great!  Please update your question and close it.